# How to dispatch a response data form axios with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, state

Hello evrybody i need help. Thanks in advance.

I can not get this data in my state, this data is on an URI and i get it with axios

```
[
{
_id: "5fe498844ff31d0c4a72e726",
id: 11,
category: "Clothes",
name: "Winter Jacket for Men, All sizes",
price: 19
},
{
_id: "5fe498844ff31d0c4a72e71e",
id: 3,
category: "Clothes",
name: "Jeans Shorts for Boys Small",
price: 56
},
{
_id: "5fe498844ff31d0c4a72e72b",
id: 16,
category: "Clothes",
name: "Winter Jacket for Men, All sizes",
price: 19
},
{
_id: "5fe498844ff31d0c4a72e71f",
id: 4,
category: "Clothes",
name: "Leather Wallet Brown Style",
price: 19
},
]
```

Axios script:
( i get the response )

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getProducts = () => {
  return new Promise((onSuccess, onFail) => {
    axios
    .get("api/products")
    .then((response, error) => {
      if (!response || error) {
        return onFail(`Response failure : ${error}`);
      }
      onSuccess(response);
      console.log(response) **//return promise response**
    });
    
  });
  
};
```

Here the reducer , i get the response data in the fetch function.
i tried to write "response => response.data.json()" but i get an error "json() is not an function")

```
import { getProducts } from "../../service/index";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: [],
};

function productsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADPRODUCTS": {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
}
export default productsReducer;



**//Fetch the response form Axios : **

export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    getProducts()
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "LOADPRODUCTS",
          playload: data,
        });
        console.log(data); **// data is returned **
      });
  };
};
```

The state component is "undefined" after the dispatch works. But i need an array with the playload data from the reducer.

```
import React from "react";
import "./GallerieProduits.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchProducts } from "../../redux/products/productsReducer";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function GallerieProduits() {
  const  {products}  = useSelector((state) => ({
    ...state.productsReducer
  
  }));

  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // A revoir

  useEffect(() => {
    if (products.length === 0) {
      dispatch(fetchProducts());
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(products) **// returned undefined**
```

here the redux store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import productsReducer from './products/productsReducer.js'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    productsReducer
})

const Store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default Store;
```

Thanks for read me :)

Comment: why are you using two .then() on your axios call? The first one will return response.data and you can just use that? The second one will return undefined

Comment: also you mentioned json() was not a function? Axios handles that for you in the first response, unlike fetch where you would have to use json().

Comment: Thank you for answer me, i use two .then() because "dispatch" doesn't work with "reponse.data" , the second is not undefined because the "console.log(data)" give me the object data.

Comment: ok could you sandbox this? Also, first then you can deconstruct data .then(( { data } ) => )

Comment: ok , it is my first time with axios , i didnt know for convert to json directly, thank you .

Comment: no probs check out https://saracemal.medium.com/axios-vs-fetch-5fd37990e5ff for more info

Comment: Hello , i found what was the bug, im so tied because i lost 2 day for this :  in my reducer i write "action.payload" instead "action.playload" .. i just forgot the first "l" , thank you for accompany me.